# SetBinding and Relationship

Tags: c#, wpf, relationship

I currently have a Dataset which consists of three tables. These three tables are then linked via data relations.

I want to be able to set bindings to textbox controls and others, providing information from all three tables, while being able to navigate using a CollectionViewSource.

I currently have the following:

```
var con = Database.GetConnection();
RefundsDS = new DataSet();
RefundAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MemberMoment WHERE RefundRequestedOn IS NOT NULL", con);
RefundAdapter.Fill(RefundsDS, "MemberMoment");

RefundAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SpecialMomentID, MomentName, MomentDateTime FROM SpecialMoment", con);
RefundAdapter.Fill(RefundsDS, "SpecialMoment");

RefundAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT MemberNo, FirstName, Surname FROM Member", con);
RefundAdapter.Fill(RefundsDS, "Member");

Relation = new DataRelation ("MemberToMM", RefundsDS.Tables["Member"].Columns["MemberNo"], RefundsDS.Tables["MemberMoment"].Columns["MemberNo"]);
RefundsDS.Relations.Add(Relation);

Relation = new DataRelation("SpecialMomentToMM", RefundsDS.Tables["SpecialMoment"].Columns["SpecialMomentID"], RefundsDS.Tables["MemberMoment"].Columns["SpecialMomentID"]);
RefundsDS.Relations.Add(Relation);

RefundViewSource.Source = RefundsDS;
this.DataContext = RefundViewSource; 

OrderIDTxt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "MemberMoment/MemberMomentNo");
MomentNameTxt.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "SpecialMoment/MomentName");
```

Typically to navigate through the DataRows, I use: CollectionViewSoureObject.MoveCurrentToPrevious()

and so on however this doesn't work, probably because it's a DataSet.

How can I amend this?

**Update:** Never mind problem solved, used a JOIN select statement instead and worked with a single DataTable, much easier.

Comment: Instead of putting an answer into question, please post it separately below. And then accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using multiple joins on a single datatable instead.